# SDL_GetWindowID always returns 1

Tags: sdl, sdl-2

When running this code on Mac (10.14.6), it always prints that the window id is 1. I'm creating multiple windows, with one window per process. What am I doing wrong? On Linux, I get unique IDs that are large (around 6 digits)

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    "cool_title", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, width,
    height, SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
printf("Created window with id %d\n", SDL_GetWindowID(window));
```

Comment: Do you create several windows in a single program, or one window per program? [Docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowID) don't say that the ID should be unique across different programs.

Comment: One window per process. Each process is a child of the same parent process. Haha, the docs don't say much at all :p.

Comment: The macOS behavior is what I'd expect given the [`next_object_id` logic in `SDL_CreateWindow()`](https://github.com/SDL-mirror/SDL/blob/master/src/video/SDL_video.c#L1484).  Kind of a long shot but anything change on Linux if you use `%u` in your `printf()`?  `SDL_GetWindowID()` returns an `unsigned int`, not an `int`.

Comment: Oh gosh ><. Turns out I was using X commands on linux to get window ids, not by calling SDL_GetWindowId. Ok, so it looks like this is the same behavior on Mac and Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was mistaken -- this happens on both Mac and Linux. SDL_GetWindowID will return 1 for the first window of every process, and increment by 1 for each new window.